# Passing JSON and Parameters to Factory from Controller in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, factory, ngresource

I have a factory that I'm using to update my data in my rest service. If I hard code the id in it updates just fine, if I try to pass a paremeter in with my json document, the json is passed to the rest service but the paremeter isn't being passed to the factory so my restUrl isn't being properly generated as its missing the itemId.

factory:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('updateItem', function ($resource) {

      return $resource('http://someserviceUrl/items/:itemId', {}, {
        update: {method: 'PUT', params: {itemId: '@itemId'}}
      });


  });
```

controller:

```
    $scope.itemId = 21;
    var itemData = {"orderItem":  {"itemHdr": {
          "itemId": "",
          "itemDescription":"Item Description",
          "typeCd": "someType",
          "salesPgm":"thisProgram",
          "onSale": true
        }
};

  updateRfp.update($scope.itemData,$scope.itemId)
    .$promise.then(function(res) {
    console.log('updateItem.update triggered!');
    $scope.results = 'Item '+ res.code + ' has been saved.';


  });
```

Am I not passing the itemId correctly? The documentation I have read shows this method of passing variables between controller and factory but it doesn't show how to do it when you are doing a combination of json and a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) says

```
// Now call update passing in the ID first then the object you are updating
Notes.update({ id:$id }, note);
```

So looks like you should pass Id as object and swap arguments

Comment: Ah yes, I had things turned around. Thanks for pointing that out! :) So my update looks like this now - updateRfp.update({itemId:$scope.itemId},$scope.itemData)   - For the benefit of anyone else who may be struggling with this.